# How to access vuetify in dynamic single file components using http-vue-loader?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, vue-loader, http-vue-loader

I am trying to access vuetify inside a component I dynamically get from http-vue-loader.  I received an error that says vuetify components weren't registered.  I then try to import the needed components with a couple different methods with no avail.  The methods I tried below didn't work.

```
require('@/node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css')
------------
<style scoped lang="scss" src="@/node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.css"></style>
```

"import" syntaxd also doesn't work as well because I am using module.exports = {} instead of export default { } due to http-vue-loader requirements.  Does anyone have a solution for this?  I am using webpack.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to access them via
`Vue.options.components.XXX`

Eg `Vue.options.components.VIcon`